# Perl script to convert a binary number to a decimal number

Tags: perl, binary, decimal

I have to write a Perl script that converts a binary number, specified as an
argument, to a decimal number. In the question there's a hint to use the *reverse* function.

We have to assume that the binary number is in this format

[image: Binary]

EDIT: This is what I've progressed to (note this is code from my textbook that I've messed with):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# dec2.pl: Converts decimal number to binary
#
die("No arguments\n") if ( $#ARGV == -1 ) ;

foreach $number (@ARGV) {
    $original_number = $number ;
    until ($number == 0 ) {
        $bit = $number % 2 ;
        unshift (@bit_arr, $bit) ;
        $number = int($number / 2 );
    }
    $binary_number = join ("", @bit_arr) ;
    print reverse ("The decimal number of $binary_number is $original_number\n");
    $#bit_arr = -1;
}
```

When executed:

```
>./binary.pl 8
The decimal number of 1000 is 8
```

I don't know how to word it to make the program know to add up all of the 1's in the number that is inputted.

Comment: Can you envision what the solution would be without code? i.e., using pen and paper? That would be the first step, because if you don't know how to solve the problem, no amount of code is going to help.

Comment: No. I've never done conversion before.

Comment: Then that's where you need to start. You go from right to left, mapping the `1` bits to powers of 2 that correspond to their positions (2^0, 2^1, 2^2, etc.) and dropping the `0` bits. Then you sum everything up.

Comment: @user3313728 this will be a useful post to read, it documents both a way to perform the conversion and why it mathematically makes sense: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86207/converting-decimalbase-10-numbers-to-binary-by-repeatedly-dividing-by-2

Comment: As far as I can see, that script converts a number to binary. Your task is the opposite.

Comment: Aw geez, you're right.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen that is for decimal to binary. does it still apply when converting binary to decimal?

Comment: @user3313728 I've given you the algorithm---does it not make sense? Here's an [illustrated explanation](https://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-number-system.html) as well. Using that, how do you think you would approach the problem?

Comment: I watched this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJjEuE6gZ1w so I have a much better idea of how to convert it on paper. Now I just need to put it in Perl.

Comment: I've made some progress and put it in the description.

Comment: The script you just posted just converts a decimal number to binary and not the other way around.  Additionally the use of "reverse" is gratuitous.  The idea of the assignment is for you to walk through the arbitrary long string of '0' and '1' given on the command-line and build a number.  We could do that for you, but that's not what we're here to do.

Comment: We've spent only 2 classes going over Perl, and before then, I had no idea it even existed. Can you give me a hint, a clue, anything to help me along because I have no idea what I'm doing? I'm extremely new to this (which for some reason, someone edited out of the post), and am not a programmer by habit.

Comment: As I've said multiple times, this isn't even a Perl problem yet; this is a math problem. Here's how to get the binary number in the proper format to do something with it: `my @arr = reverse(split(//, '111110100'));` Now show us the math that needs to be done.

Comment: (2^0 + 2^2 + 2^4 + 2^5 + 2^6 + 2^7 + 2^8) = (4 + 16 + 32 + 64 + 128 + 256) =  500 @MattJacob

Answer (score 3):

You could just use **sprintf** to do the converting for you...

```
sprintf("%d", 0b010101);  # Binary string 010101 -> Decimal 21

sprintf("%b", 21)         # Decimal 21 -> Binary 010101 string
```

Of course, you can also just **eval** a binary string with **0b** in front to indicate binary:

```
my $binary_string = '010101';
my $decimal = eval("0b$binary");  # 21
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to use `reverse`, but it makes it easy to think about the problem with respect to exponents and array indices.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = '111110100';
my @bits = reverse(split(//, $str));
my $sum = 0;

for my $i (0 .. $#bits) {
    next unless $bits[$i];
    $sum += 2 ** $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are suppose to convert from a binary to decimal, not the other way around, which you means you take an input like `$binary = '1011001';`.

The first thing you need to do is obtain the individual bits (a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, etc) from that. We're talking about splitting the string into its individual digits.

```
for my $bit (split(//, $binary)) {
   ...
}
```

That should be a great starting point. With that, you have all that you need to apply the following refactoring of the formula you posted:

n = ( ( ( ... )*2 + a<sub>2</sub> )*2 + a<sub>1</sub> )*2 + a<sub>0</sub>

[I have no idea why `reverse` would be recommended. It's possible to use it, but it's suboptimal.]

Comment: Thanks to your illustration, I saw that a recursive solution was a solution. Still (unsuccessfully) working on an iterative one.